# How to choose all column of a single table in a joined table?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a query that is like this:

`SELECT * FROM A JOIN B`

Table `A` and `B` are almost equal, but I use the join to filter on certain rows. Now my result table is having all columns twice, and this is causing referencing trouble where I am using this table. Therefore I would like to only show table `A`'s columns. Is there a more easy way to achieve this than retyping all column names on the spot of `*`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want the columns from `A`, then use:

```
select A.*
```

You can add additional columns as you like:

```
select A.*, B.special_column
```